# ERROR: Preparation failed: error connecting to Kubernetes: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, gitlab, integration

when i try to run the pipeline after intragrating the kubernetes cluster to the gitlab using gitlabkubernetesAgent, iam getting this error can anyone look into this please...

Comment: no details given, subject is server based behaviours or infra.  Voting to close

Comment: Please elaborate your problem and what you have tried to fix the problem. Remember this StackOverflow is for development-related questions. If you have problems in Kubernetes, but with setting up servers, or infra-related, maybe it's better be in [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/)